# How do I use the `--node` option in browserify with the API

Tags: browserify

The CLI has the advanced option `--node` that bundles for use within node.

The documentation states:

> ```
> --node
>
> Alias for --bare and --no-browser-field.
> ```

The API option for turning off the browser field is the easy but then the `--bare` option confuses me.

> ```
> --bare
>
> Alias for both --no-builtins, --no-commondir, and sets --insert-global-vars
> to just "__filename,__dirname". This is handy if you want to run bundles in
> node.
> ```

In particular, the `--insert-global-vars` really confuses me.

So here's the question:

#### How do I get the same result as `--bare` using the `browserify([files] [, opts])` api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code that sets options based on the `--bare` argument according to the [Browserify source code](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/blob/master/bin/args.js#L72):

```js
if (argv.bare) {
    argv.builtins = false;
    argv.commondir = false;
    if (argv.igv === undefined) {
        argv.igv = '__filename,__dirname';
    }
}

if (argv.igv) {
    var insertGlobalVars = {};
    var wantedGlobalVars = argv.igv.split(',');
    Object.keys(insertGlobals.vars).forEach(function (x) {
        if (wantedGlobalVars.indexOf(x) === -1) {
            insertGlobalVars[x] = undefined;
        }
    });
}
```

so you should pass this to the `opts` parameter of `browserify()`:

```js
const files = [...];
const opts = {
    builtins: false,
    commondir: false,
    insertGlobalVars: ['__filename', '__dirname']
};

browserify(files, opts);
```

Comment: oh i found it in the source code too. Thanks for the help. this works!

Comment: and for anyone else who stumbles upon this, `opts.browserField: false` should also be set to mimic the `--node` CLI option.